# Precise Puppy 5.7.1JP input language hotkey

Tags: puppy-linux

How do I switch between English and Japanese keyboard input in Precise Puppy Linux 5.7.1 Japanese Edition? Is there a GUI menu option? Is there a keyboard shortcut?

EDIT

I found this page with SCIM instructions.

http://puppylinux.org/wikka/GetScimWorkingAfterInstall

When I press `Ctrl-Space` the SCIM bar doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Country Settings to *ja_JP* Japanese in Puppy Quick Setup, then restart X.

In Japanese Country Setting, `Ctrl-Space` will cause the SCIM bar to appear.